# Zip a JSON object before sending in PHP

Tags: php, json, zip

I'm interested in zipping the text output from a JSON object on a server before transporting it to my mobile device that has requested the object.  A small test of the txt zipping will reduce its size by about 80%!  This is great for mobile!  :)

I don't really need to save the zip file i create on the server at all, just have it reside in memory, then echo it out.  I can unzip it on the android side no problem.

Anyways, I've done a little manipulation but I haven't been able to come up with anything that works, here's what I have so far:

```
while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
   $output[]=$e;
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->addFromString("test",(json_encode($output)));
echo $zip;
```

I know im probably doing something massively wrong, im not very familiar with php.  My $q is a cursor containing lots of sql rows, and if I use `print(json_encode($output));` instead of all the zip shenanigans it works fine to output the raw text.

I suppose it doesnt have to be zip compression, but any compression would be helpful if you could point me in a proper direction I can likely figure it out.  Thanks!

Comment: If you’re using a webserver to provide the PHP data consider using standard gzip/deflate. Further zipping it shouldn’t help that much. If your client-end can ungzip/deflate that should be enough and simpler to implement (as you don’t have to implement it at all).

Comment: +1 question related to my interests.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use `ob_start` with [`ob_gzhandler`](http://php.net/ob_gzhandler):

```
if(function_exists('ob_gzhandler')) ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
else ob_start();

echo json_encode($output);
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: +1, Good answer good question. @knittl can you explain how will the zipped/encoded data will be unzipped/decoded to json on client-side.

Comment: @Imram: clients (browsers) will automatically deflate data (probably send the correct http headers, if it's not working out of the box). decoding json is not necessary, because json is already valid javascript code.

Comment: After much monkeying around with android's gzip http request capabilities, I got this working.  My server (and my player's data plans) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Server Side:Create a JSON object that contain only a property that is a byte array that is the JSON object zipped and send it to client.
Client Side:Unzip the byte array contained in the object to obtain the original JSON DATA.
Pro:5X Fastest communication Server-Client,less IO work for Server.
Required more CPU work fromServer.
Take your consideration :P